# How to show Control only when fully created (.NET)

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating complex UserControl, what is annoying to me is application shows it partially during creation mode.
Means end user can see all creation / draw process (controls placed on this UserControl appearing with delay, gradient boxes draw they fill etc)

I'm pretty sure there is some **command hiding this process and showing control only when it is fully drawn**...

Can someone advice how to archive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mhh I don't think exist something exactly like this, but there are these things:

- **SuspendLayout** (This does what you want, doesn't show the drawing process, ResumeLayout to show layout changes)
- Visible (you can change it when drawing control)
- Paint event

You can also call Invalidate (which force redrawing of the form)

This works for initialization quite well, but I don't understand if you want it **every time** the control is painted or only when is created

However I don't have an idea on how to intercept "before drawing" and "after drawing" (Paint I think it's triggered before drawing, not sure)

Comment: Re SuspendLayout - on what control I shall fire that? on parent or on currently being created

Comment: I've archived that with combination of visible property - much better now! Thanks

Comment: Nothing,  btw SuspendLayout should be called on "your control which contains a lot of controls", if the parent is suspended, all childs are suspended

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your UserControl has been marked to be double buffered. This ensures that when the client area of the UserControl needs drawing it is done so onto an off-screen buffer and then when completed it is blitted to the screen. This makes it atomic and you should not see drawing actions as they occur. To add this use the following in your UserControl constructor...

```
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                 ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

Comment: Better but still see this delayed painting effect... Any advice(s) ?

Comment: If your UserControl contains other controls then they also need to perform double buffering as well.

Comment: @Maciej: Watch his comment, is important. I find his suggestion more useful than mine, maybe preserves you from doing some boring work with code

Comment: I'm using your both advices to get this working. I can see some delay during drawing components when using  only buffering. Only combination with visible property gives more or less what I like...